# Error installing OpenWebRTC in ios

Tags: ios, cocoapods

Hi i am new for ios and in my i am trying to install "OpenWebRTC" pod files like below formate and when i trying to install them i am getting below errors please help me

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
target 'videoCallApp' do
pod 'OpenWebRTC', '~> 0.1'
pod 'OpenWebRTC-SDK',  :git => 'https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk.git'
end
```

### error:-

```
Analyzing dependencies
Pre-downloading: `OpenWebRTC-SDK` from `https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk.git`
Downloading dependencies
Installing OpenWebRTC (0.3.1)

[!] Error installing OpenWebRTC
[!] /usr/bin/curl -f -L -o /var/folders/7y/xc2v__vx44n0t1d875wv3zbh0000gn/T/d20160611-17948-zbondp/file.zip http://static.verkstad.net/OpenWebRTC_0.3.1.zip --create-dirs --netrc

  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue and sorted it by using the following suggestion from [here](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc-ios-sdk/issues/17)

> Try running rm -rf Pods/ Podfile.lock and then re-run pod install.

Once I did this it worked perfectly. Hope this helps.